# Filter collection on same attribute with different values

Tags: collection, sales-order

I want to filter collection for same attribute having two either values.

example:

```
->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id',Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getGroupId())   


->addFieldToFilter('sales_org',Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getSalesOrgId())


->addFieldToFilter('sales_office',Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getSalesOfficeId())
```

**My question is.**

If `cutomer_group_id == 12` then it should have `sales_org and sales_office value`. else if `customer_group_id == 13` then it `should be null in sales_org and sales_office`.

How can i achieve this filters.

Answer (score 3):

**AND** Query Condition

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attributecode1', array('like' => '%ch%'));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attributecode2', array('eq' => '1'));
```

**OR** Query Condition

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                array(
                    'attribute' => 'atrributecode1',
                    'like' => '%ch%'),
                array(
                    'attribute' => 'attributecode2',
                    'eq' => '1')
            ));
```

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement , need to `write  direction  sql collection filter` by

```
$collection=Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');


$read = Mage::getSingleton( 'core/resource' )->getConnection( 'core_read' );
 $whereCondition = array(
        $read->quoteInto('cutomer_group_id = ?', 12),
        $read->quoteInto('sales_org IS  NOT NULL'),
 $read->quoteInto('sales_office IS NOT NULL'),
 );
 $collection->getSelect()->Where(implode(' AND ', $whereCondition));

 $orwhereCondition = array(
        $read->quoteInto('cutomer_group_id = ?', 13),
        $read->quoteInto(' sales_org IS NULL'),
 $read->quoteInto('sales_office IS NULL'),
 );
 echo $collection->getSelect()->orWhere(implode(' AND ', $orwhereCondition));
```

You can use.But **it not a good idea**